# Workflow Tasks are getting assigned to an OLD domain account

Tags: designer-workflow

We migrated to a new domain by rebuilding a server in the new domain and plugging the old content database into it.  Then we ran the migrate user scripts.

STILL we are having problems with the old domain accounts getting assigned tasks that should be going to the new domain user account emails.

repro:

1) create a list and use people picker control in InfoPath form for Workflow Assignee.
2) create an item in the list and use the people picker to select someone in the new domain.
3) start a workflow that assigns a task to the person selected in the form.

Expected: Assigned to the new domain user account email
Actual: assigned to the OLD domain user account email

Comment: Have you tried recreating the User Profile Service?

Comment: yes we figured out I was witnessing the SIP Address pointed to the old domain account.  we are still attempting to clean this up but they are getting assigned to the correct user profiles.  editing the SIP Address of the profiles one at a time seems to rectify the mis-information problem (where we'd hover over the user in the UI and it would show the old domain account profile because that is what was looking at SIP Address).